# Iterating Nested JSON to array of objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I get a JSON response like this:

```
{
"20150917":
 {
     "Daily01sec":
        {
            "TG01152600000": "\/20150917\/Daily01sec\/TG0115260.bin",
            "TG01152600600": "\/20150917\/Daily01sec\/TG0115260.bin"
        }
    },
"201510":
    {
        "05":
        {
            "Daily01sec":
            {
                "TG01152780600": "\/201510\/05\/Daily01sec\/TG01152780600.bin"                       
            }
        }
    },
"201509":
    {
        "05":
        {
            "Daily01sec":
            {
                "TG01152780600": "\/201510\/05\/Daily01sec\/TG01152780600.bin"                     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want an array of indexes of and its value to the corresponding data.

I want to have data["20150917"],data["201510"],data["201509"]
and the corresponding information for it.

Actually the nested data would be an array of nested data in it,

Can be parsed with angularJS ng-repeat? any idea?

Comment: my target is to convert the first nested objects into array of objects

Comment: `var object = JSON.parse(json_text);` BTW your json_text seems to be not consistent.

Comment: @MaxZoom my code seems parsed JSON, also if I do that, it also says SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: @MaxZoom I can't get what you mean by the last elements!

Comment: @MaxZoom I removed those last commas

Comment: Please check if my post below helps

Comment: @Pamblam not true in older versions of IE...any trailing comma will break all scripts

Comment: which part will be nested array? Also, do you have control over source structure?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript an object is an associative array.

In other words `myobj.data` is the same thing as `myobj['data']` - the two can be used interchangeably. So all you have to do is parse your JSON (if it's not already) and you're good to go.

```
data = JSON.parse(json); 
console.log(data['20150917']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/byjawop8/

**EDIT**

You're looking for `for..in` syntax, which looks like this:

```
for(index in json){
    document.getElementById('r').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', index+" " + json[index]['05']['Daily01sec']['TG01152780600'] + "<br>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjedwLws/1/

**EDIT AGAIN**

I gave you what you needed in my last edit, but I'll give you one more hint. This function iterates through the JSON, and as long as it's formatted in the way you posted above, this will convert the whole thing into an array you can easily iterate through.

```
function arrayConvert(json){
    var arr = [];
    for(index in json){
        var obj = json[index];
        var key = null;
        while(typeof obj == 'object'){
            for(ind in obj){
                if(key == null) key = ind;
                obj = obj[ind];
            }
        }
        arr.push({'key':key, 'val':obj});
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yjedwLws/2/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't know the index "20150917", because it may change in another JSON I get from the server! hence I need iterating thorough them easily,  this is the problem you get me?

Comment: @Ebrahim - Ok, I answered your question, check my edit. If this helps please hit the check mark.

Comment: thanks, I need to iterate in various JSON responses like this. so I don't know the structure at first, your answer is well, when I know the case and is not dynamically changing!

Comment: answer has nothing to do with generating an angular view  with `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Ebrahim - I've given you the answer AND done the work for you. Please hit the checkmark.

Comment: @Pamblam thanks, but is not the correct answer, you know , it is need the real answer, you want fake rankings?

Comment: @Pamblam suggest you read the whole question before giving OP a hard time. Clearly states trying to push this into an angular view. I do agree however the data source structure does need clarification

Comment: @Pamblam you charge as much as you want, please don't waste your and mine also others time!

Comment: @Ebrahim, I've now given you the answer three times. All you have to do is use the function i posted to flatten out your object (but change `[]` to `{}`) and use the resulting object in your `ng-repeat`. read the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @Pamblam thanks for your all assist, but It is not the answer, maybe I should say the problem like this: I have a nested object, I want each object to be an element of the array first of all, and then easily iterate through that array like using ng-repeat or what else, my problem here is that they are only objects, and I can't traverse, I want they to be firstly elements in array, then each element is an object. do you need more clarification? I sent a hangout invitation to your gmail

Comment: I don't use gmail, I have a secure protonmail account :P can you maybe make a jsfiddle but just write the expected output as HTML and forget about the JavaScript part. Just let me see what you're trying to do and maybe I can help you get there. @Ebrahim

Comment: @Pamblam please look at this file https://www.dropbox.com/s/1anji6t3cnnfj7b/Screenshot%202015-10-06%2003.06.01.jpg?dl=0 here the folder names which I receive the JSON as the server side is shown here, but they are  not sorted, I need better iteration and traverse through them, and also here is a simple JSfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ebrahimmm/ncykb0qq/5/

Comment: @Ebrahim - So, you want to iterate through just the inner paths from the JSON? - and you want to sort them? Sort by what? Alphabetically?

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell exactly what kind of output you're looking for with that screenshot of code but I will give you this advice: You're clearly trying to parse the data and the output at the same time. First get your data model into an easily traverable model, then loop through it and build your HTML. Again, if you can throw together some HTML and forget about the javascript part for now, maybe I can see what you're trying to do. @Ebrahim

Comment: wait i think you're trying to build like a breadcrubms type of thing.. i think i get it now

Comment: @Ebrahim do yourself a big favor and standardize the property names at source within the objects within arrays ... will make it trivial to put into view